# Does the earth really move round the sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system

Is there really any empirical proof that the earth moves round the sun?

I've read simple explanations using mass-gravity relation. But then some questions remain, is gravity a function of mass alone? Is mass a function of size alone? if the earth is revolving round itself, and the sun is revolving round and moving towards the black hole in the centre of the Milky Way, how can we be sure that these two movements alone do not suffice to explain night and day or change in the position of the stars with time?

Thanks.

Comment: @All: That's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm simply asking fundamental questions. How can we conclude anything about earth revolution if we do not know much about the sun.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Hi Chibueze Opata, welcome to Stack-Exchange. Please consider posting several question in different post, it helps the other users to answer them.

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: The second "duplicate" should be useful to you. Try explain **retrograde motion** with your idea for a model.